# jquery/angular scheduler implementation

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs

I have a chat application written on jquery. When user sends a message, this message is being sent to java REST endpoint. But I also want to listen for response. I think it would be good to listen other REST endpoint every second, because I have no idea how to implement it like in Facebook. So if there new message, get them and show. How to do that in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of solutions for that, but I'd suggest you do not create chat application using REST. If you want pure JS think about firebase from google (it will be realtime)/meteor or definitely using Websockets (you'll need a websocket server and you can use authobahnjs to subscribe to that server).

I do realize it's solution that's more complicated than REST, but if you ask me and probably your customers REST is really not the best choice for chat/realtime applications...

Just think of situation where you will have lots of users online and each of them will not only be sending a lot of queries (if they write fast) but as well checking for response every second. Now think if something goes wrong on the network what will happen with your server... you'll get tons of 'hanging' connections etc.

btw. ppl who tried it (like me in past) will tell you the same, no chats with polling for messages over REST! ;)

JQuery way...
Ok, just watch out for defining multiple events on the same element (that’s classic one when working with Jquery), here’s a function that should do what you want (its a post, but you can adapt it):

```
var interval = 1000;  // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'chatController.php',
            data: {action: 'getMessagesForUser', user: {user: 'data'}},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                   //do something with results     
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            }
    });
}
setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
```

You could also introduce some variable that would make sure you're not making another request before the previous one has completed etc.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is I already have rest chat app server based on jersey, and I didn't write it, I just trying to use it

Comment: Then (especially if you're up for angular2) you'd be interested in Observable.interval(time), have a look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086596/periodically-updating-observable-value-in-angular2 - in pure javascript or jquery you'll probably need to use setTimeout function, but i'd go with angular approach...

Comment: Thank you, how do you think, will it be acceptable in terms of stability/performance/scalability? Thanks

Comment: also, angular2 is not supported by IE8. It may be an issue also.

Comment: If ie8 is an issue you might want to try angular1 or yes, just use jquery. Though Jquery tends to get messy when your project grows. Stability/performance/scalability... this heavily depends on your code (and infrastructure) rather than framework. If everyone needs to learn it then it might not be the best idea, depends on your time and skills in your team.

Comment: Thank you, but I am the only developer on this project now and jquery seems to be the only avail option now. Thank you for your help.